# How to resolve the Mongo JDBC driver for below code?

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, jdbc

```
try {
Class.forName("mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to load SQLServer JDBC Driver");
e.printStackTrace();
return;
}
```

I am getting unable to load the driver

Comment: Add the driver to your classpath.

Comment: Why does your exception say it can't find SQL Server driver?  You're looking for Mongo.  Is this cut & paste code?

Answer (score 0):

Add the driver jar to your program's classpath, ClassLoader will find and load it.